# Every time I press enter in the terminal it says Karans-MacBook-Air:~ karanmunjal$. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

My name is Karan and so obviously the laptop is named Karans MacBook Air but I dont think it should show up every time I press enter. Please tell me how to fix this!

Comment: What should it say if not `Karans-MacBook-Air`?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, it is showing you the default prompt, which is your computer name, current directory and the username.

`export PS1="$"` or `export PS1="\w $"` or similar (see https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html)

should relieve you. If you're  convinced, append your custom command to `~/.bash_profile` and reopen Terminal.

Other than that, pressing enter is actually running an empty command, so after completion, the prompt returns to receive further ones. That is expected behaviour.

Just in case, you want to edit computer name, Go to System Preferences -> Sharing and edit it under Computer Name.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for answering. I got the first part. I used export PS1="$" and every now line began with a "$". But how do I make this permanent because if I reopen the terminal it again starts with the computer name, current directory and the username.
I'm an absolute beginner at coding so the lingo is a bit difficult for me to understand. Can you please provide me with the code that I can copy paste to fix it permanently?

Comment: `echo 'export PS1="\w $"' >> ~/.bash_profile` OR  `echo export PS1="$" >> ~/.bash_profile` https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371614/how-to-add-the-path-for-mysql-bin-on-mac/371665 these answers got you covered.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it