# :wq command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

When opening terminal, this line shows every time:

```
-bash: :wq: command not found
```

How can I stop it from appearing every time Terminal opens ?

Comment: When in terminal type `cat ~/.bash_profile` or `cat ~/.bashrc` and paste it here.

Comment: `sed -i '/:wq/d' ~/.bash*` should fix it ;)

Comment: @I.Am.A.Guy please add that as an **Answer**.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like there exists a line `:wq` in one of your shell’s profile files, such as `~/.bash_profile`, which was probably added as a failed attempt at quitting Vim when editing such a file.

To edit the bash profile with TextEdit, run `open -e ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal. Edit the file to remove the `:wq` line only. Save it, quit TextEdit and restart Terminal to see changes. You might want to make a copy of the file in case you're worried: `cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.bak`.

If you don’t want to use Terminal at all, see this answer [How to add the PATH for mysql bin on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371614/how-to-add-the-path-for-mysql-bin-on-mac/371665#371665) with instructions on how to edit a profile file only using GUI.

Comment: I don't understand. Please clear this answer..

Comment: @KazalGhosh see the edit.

Comment: What does this question have to do with MySQL?

Comment: @Barmar Nothing but ankii added the link as more information on editing the bash profile file using GUI.

Comment: Not adding much but instead of closing and re-opening the terminal, you can just run `source .bashrc` which should re-source the file, and even give you the error again in case you haven't yet fixed it (IIRC anyway)

Comment: @QuickishFM  I reopen Terminal faster than I can type ;-)

Comment: @QuickishFM: But then your bash session has the effects of *two* runs of slight variations of your `.bashrc`, which could cause weird problems. Opening a new terminal will usually lead to a cleaner state.

Comment: @Barmar almost as much as it has to do with Apple Macs ;-P

Answer (score 2):

You messed up when editing .bash_profile with the 'vi' editor aka 'vim'.

You did your writing in insert mode, then when you finished, you were supposed to hit `esc` to exit insert mode, then  `: w q` for command, write and quit.

You failed to hit `esc` so it inserted :wq as additional text.  You then collected yourself, tried `esc : w q` one more time, and that worked.

Fire up vim one more time, opening the file as before.

- Hit capital G to go to end of document.
- With the cursor in the wayward :wq cline, hit "dd" lower case.
- you shouldn't need to hit `esc` but do it anyway.  It may beep.
- now hit `:wq`