# environment variable edit error

Tags: terminal, mac, environment-variables

I have been trying to edit my environment variables. I referred to the sites but its not working. I should mention that I am very new to Mac
and I'm using it because my workplace has it. 
When I enter the command

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

in the Terminal, it says

```
-bash: touch: command not found
-bash: open: command not found
```

though it did open the file once before.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` print? The path variable contains a list of places to search for ‘touch’ and ‘open’, so if it’s missing or invalid your shell won’t be able to find these commands.

Comment: If it has Catalina, I doubt that bash commands would work there. in any case, you can follow this step by step guide: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371665/313842 you might need to see zsh variation for PATH syntax

Comment: `touch` is used to set the modification and access times of a file and if it doesn't exist creates it.  Out of curiosity, where (the referred sites) did you get instructions to use  that command and secondly, you said it opened it before - what changes did you make (I'm assuming you used Text Editor as it would be the default)?

Comment: @Akash, you need to install command line tools from Apple to have ```touch```. Use this command from terminal: ```xcode-select --install``` (it is free).

Answer (score 1):

First check that your path variable is working or not just type (echo $PATH) from terminal it will return the O/P like: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 
if saying "commond not found"

Then you have to PATH variable to setup path variable below steps

1) vi /etc/paths 
it's will vi editor to edit type "I" and enter below mention lines

/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

2) press esc and type wq to save exit.